# android option menu with icon

Tags: android

How to show icon with option menu.I have tried the following code but my option menu is without image icon.I am using android version 4.0 for developing app.

**Java code** :

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
             menu.add("Add Contacts").setIcon(
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            return true;
        }
```

Following is my app's screen shot

[image]

I need image to be displayed on the top of "Add Contacts" item.

Comment: Its a good question. Too bad it does not have an answer. None of these methods work.

Answer (score 4):

Override `OnPrepareOptionsMenu` and add icon from there too

and if its for above 3.0, use `android:showAsAction` in xml.

eg. `android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"`

Answer (score 4):

I tried the code in two line and it works:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add("Add Contacts");
        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom menu like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/add_contacts"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
          android:title="@string/add_contacts"
         />
</menu>
```

And then inflate it

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

More on this here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306943/android-menu-icons-are-not-displaying-when-the-api-level-is-above-10

Answer (score 2):

you can directly set this into the xml file.

```
  <item android:id="@+id/add_contacts"
  android:icon="@android:drawable/plus_icon"
  android:title="Add Contacts"/>
```

Comment: This works for me if you're showing it as an action, but if you're not (ie a dropdown options menu), it doesnt display - at least for me anyway

Answer (score 2):

You Can try Following this [Link](http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2011/04/android-simple-menu-example.html).

Check this out and tell me if it worked or not.

Or you can do some thing like this.
Create menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:id="@+id/next"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_next"
              android:title="@string/next" />
      <item android:id="@+id/previous"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_previous"
            android:title="@string/previous" />
      <item android:id="@+id/list"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_list"
            android:title="@string/list" /> 
</menu>
```

And now you will be able to set ICON on menu

Now in CreateOptionMenu

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
      return true;
    }
```

And to access that menu.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.next:
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen the " + getResources().getString(R.string.next) + " menu option",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
      …
      default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Ohk then you can try by creating menu.xml file and you can set the menu Items in that and also set ICON in that.

Comment: Check that code I have edited the answer. If it works or not let me know.

Comment: Or check this Link  :[link] http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-menus-part-1-options-menu/

Comment: Are you using android 4.0.?? If yes then there it don't show the option menu ICON. as per my knowledge.

Comment: Ohk. Good. Keep Going... :)

Comment: And if you find it as answer then please tag it as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To enable Option Menu with Icons:

Wrap the Items with an `Item` with `showAsAction="always"` and a `Menu`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:title="@string/title_menu"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_icon_menu"
        app:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action1"
                android:orderInCategory="100"
                android:title="@string/action1"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_icon_action1"
                app:showAsAction="never" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use some following attribute in manifest file then it's will be show your icon....

```
<activity android:name=".ui.CategoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        **android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"**></activity>
```

It's work fine for me...:)
+1 for my own effort...

**must be enter.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use the @drawable only when setting your menu item.

OR

Simply put the @drawable before the title declaration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app    ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
  android:id      ="@+id/addToFavorites"
  android:icon = "@drawable/ic_favorite_border_white_24dp"
  android:title = "Hello"
  app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
  android:id      ="@+id/about"
  android:title   ="About"
  app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score -1):

the problem is the Androidmanifest.xml.
Remove    `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` and it will work just fine