# Android : How to set ClickListener for Pop-Menu in Card View?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

> I'm developing an Android  Music Streaming application. I have Certain
>   card views and each card view has some pop up menus (as shown in
>   image) . I want to get the id of the card that is clicked. The
>   albumadapter class extends recyclerview and i can't set the id of the
>   card that is clicked. it is showing error that is red lines.

[image]

The code i have set which is having error is inside the lines..

AlbumsAdapter.java..

```
public class AlbumsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlbumsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Album> albumList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, count;
        public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;



        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            overflow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.overflow);
        }
    }


    public AlbumsAdapter(Context mContext, List<Album> albumList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.albumList = albumList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.album_card, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Album album = albumList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(album.getName());
        holder.count.setText(album.getNumOfSongs() + " songs");

        // loading album cover using Glide library
        Glide.with(mContext).load(album.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

        holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showPopupMenu(holder.overflow);

            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Showing popup menu when tapping on 3 dots
     */
    private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
        // inflate menu
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_album, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
        popup.show();
    }

    /**
     * Click listener for popup menu items
     */
    class MyMenuItemClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

        public MyMenuItemClickListener() {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_add_favourite:
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Add to favourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_play_next:
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Play next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                case R.id.action_save_file:
                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view;
                TextView as = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.title);
        String qq = as.getText().toString();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, qq, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (qq.equals("Save File")){
            Intent i=new Intent(AlbumAdapter.this,Youtube_player.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

                    return true;
                //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                default:
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I need this code to be used in the class..

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view;
                TextView as = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.title);
        String qq = as.getText().toString();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, qq, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (qq.equals("Save File")){
            Intent i=new Intent(AlbumAdapter.this,Youtube_player.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling a Menu Item Click Event - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479992/handling-a-menu-item-click-event-android)

Answer (score 1):

[**Here is Full working demo**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39072273/how-to-implement-image-with-text-in-menu-options-in-android/39072458#39072458)

```
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, view);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.one:
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return true;
                            case R.id.two:
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return true;
                            case R.id.three:
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "3",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.main);
                popupMenu.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: where should i paste the code. on the main activity or the the code which i pasted here

Comment: please elaborate i didt get problem yet completely.