# Menu Button does not appear for option menu

Tags: android, optionmenu

I am creating a option menu in a no title bar theme, bt the problem is my phone does not contain any menu button. So how can i make the on Screen menu button to appear. I tried my code in a friends phone(with menu button) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306943/android-menu-icons-are-not-displaying-when-the-api-level-is-above-10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the target sdk version to less then 11(say 10) here in manifest xml:

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```